# Can't connect to the internet (Stuck on connecting)

Tags: internet

I've been using Ubuntu for years, and Ubuntu 18.04 for several months. Today, randomly my laptop stopped connecting to any network. I would choose a wifi and it would say connecting for a while and then fail.

Same for Ethernet connections.

Comment: You might check your hardware... I'd try testing some third party wireless card such as https://www.alfa.net.my/products/Alfa-AWUS036NH-802.11n-WIRELESS-N---USB-Wifi-adapter/4

Comment: No problem there, my machine is dual booted and no issues on windows

Comment: Well there goes that idea :/.... What does the journal say when you try to connect (open a terminal type `journalctl -f` then try and connect)

Comment: http://imgur.com/M7uASMM

Comment: Really sorry for the link and for clicking an image, I know that's retarded but there was no way to get the message here as is

Comment: Mmmm I'm gonna be completely honest with you, i can't read whats in the image, between the small text and the lines wrapping. you can just pipe the output of `journalctl > my_file.txt` then find a way to post that?

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08844630978451745442

Comment: Never used `AppArmor` but try [disabling](http://www.techytalk.info/disable-and-remove-apparmor-on-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions/) it and see if you can connect to the internet after

Comment: Disabled it, no change

Comment: I am unfortunatley out of ideas atm, if anything comes to me though ill post again :(

Answer (score 1):

I just had a the same issue: wifi just stopped working on Ubuntu 18.04 but works on Windows in the same hardware. Rebooting the pc didn't solve the issue, but rebooting the router did. I have no idea why, but the router was refusing connections from the Ubuntu machine specifically.

I know it's an old question, but it was the first I found when searching for this issue. I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I could connect to wifi after I disconnected my cell phone from the router.
What was strange is that before disconnecting that cell phone, I could not connect to another cell phone serving as a wifi hotspot. Or maybe this all was just a coincidence.

Ubuntu 22.04.01 jammy; Lenovo notebook.